# Safari image.onload event not firing with Blob url

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, html5-canvas

I am trying to get this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrohlf/HGFZ4/1/) from MDN working in Safari. It works quite nicely in Chrome and FF.

Specifically, the `onload` callback of the image does not appear to be firing in Safari 7.0.3. Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates this behavior (run it with the dev console in your browser open):

http://jsfiddle.net/qrohlf/HGFZ4/1/

I think that this is probably a bug in Safari - any ideas on how to work around it?

Comment: It is also not working in Safari 7.1

Answer (score 16):

In your jsfiddle example, the `onload` event is not fired because an error has occurred. Try attach an `onerror` handler and you will see it fired.

Unfortunately, the error object doesn't tell you what is wrong.

Indeed the problem is the `Blob`'s `type` doesn't expect the charset part. Try removing `;charset=utf-8` and it will work.